# How can I receive ringing on all the numbers configured in call handling and forwarding in RingCentral while using web phone?

Tags: webrtc, ringcentral

I did configuration under user's call handling and forwarding for Ring would go on all the configured group numbers. It is working in Softphone but not in webphone using WebRTC.

Comment: Could you please provide more details when you say "working in Softphone but not in webphone"?

Do you mean:
* Inbound calls are not ringing on the WebPhone which is configured as a member of a call group?
* Inbound calls are not ringing on the WebPhone at all?
* Forwarded calls are not ringing on the WebPhone?

Comment: Do you still need assistance with this question?

Comment: Yes, I am still stuck at this problem.

When some calls on the main number of RingCentral and press 1, 2 or 3. we should get a ring simultaneously on three numbers which we have configured.

Those three numbers are connected in desk phone and it will be logged in webphone of RingCentral as well which we have developed on our software.

We are getting an incoming call in desk phone simultaneously on all the three numbers but we are not getting a ring in webphone. But, when the user press direct extension of the user (e. g. 11) then we are getting a call on webphone.

Comment: If I am following what you're describing, it seems like a possible configuration issue.

Do you mean that 1, 2, 3 are each configured as a Call Group and you expect the numbers associated with that call group to ring simultaneously?

Comment: Yes, It should ring simultaneously and it is working in desk phone but not in webphone. We are not getting the ring in the web phone.

I am getting inbound call in web phone while user pressed direct extension of the user but not while user pressed 1, 2 or 3.

Comment: This seems as if it could be either a bug or a configuration issue.

Could you please create a developer support case to investigate this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, we do not support the simultaneous ringing for web-phone through  call handling and forwarding configuration. The reason is,  the call might end up in a call-loop and get disconnected.

The workaround would be to create a call-queue. Disable the voice mail to an extension. This should make the call enter the call queue and ring the webphone and softphone simultaneously .